# Approximate Asian option price under Heston Model

Tags: options, heston

I am looking to see if there is a formula or a derivation at least of an approximation of an Asian (Average Price) option under the heston model of stochastic volatility.

Please advise

Answer (score 3):

There is a [closed-form pricing formula for the Geometric Asian Option in the Heston model](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330297616_Geometric_Asian_Options_Pricing_under_the_Double_Heston_Stochastic_Volatility_Model_with_Stochastic_Interest_Rate/fulltext/5c37fbab299bf12be3be3629/Geometric-Asian-Options-Pricing-under-the-Double-Heston-Stochastic-Volatility-Model-with-Stochastic-Interest-Rate.pdf) (the only non-paywalled link I can find shows the double-Heston price, Heston is a special case of double-Heston), but not for the Arithmetic Asian option ([this is also the case in Black-Scholes](http://www.quantopia.net/asian-options-iii-geometric-asian/)).

For Arithmetic Asian prices, a numerical technique like Monte-Carlo will be required.

However, the prices of Geometric and Arithmetic Asian options are very similar and highly correlated, [so that the geometric price can be used as a control variate in the Monte Carlo simulation](https://www.quantopia.net/improving-monte-carlo-control-variates/), vastly increasing the accuracy of the calculation for a set number of paths.

*Update 28-07-2021*:

For anyone looking for implementations, analytic pricing engines for geometric asian options under Heston are [available in QuantLib](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/tree/master/ql/experimental/asian), and the MC pricer for arithmetic asian options supports the use of the [geometric asian option as a control variate](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/pull/966)